# Airflow python returned value handling via XCOM

Tags: airflow

I am trying to create an Airflow dag as described below:
I have a quite large python code that eventually creates a file. 
the file is created with a specific name e.g `sales20180802130200.json`

the following Airflow task is `s3BucketUpload` operator. it needs to get the name of the file in order to make the upload to s3.

the first python file can probably be ran by a `bashOperator`. how can it create an Xcom key with the name of the file? Is there any other way to pass the value?

Thanks
Shaby

Comment: You can use a Python operator to run the Python code and push the name of the file to XCom.

Answer (score 0):

As long as path argument is included to template arguments in operator class Airflow will interpolate values for you. I don't know how s3BucketUpload operator looks like, so I'll assume argument names.

```
class s3BucketUploadOperator(BaseOperator):
    # this tuple is not used by anything in my operator classes and is not passed anywhere
    template_fields = ('local_path', 's3_path', )
    ...

def py_fn(task_instance, **context):
    task_instance.xcom_push(key='file_name', value='file.name')

py_task = PythonOperator(
    dag=dag,
    task_id='py_task',
    provide_context=True,
    python_callable=py_fn
)

s3_task = s3BucketUploadOperator(
    dag=dag,
    task_id='s3_task',
    s3_conn_id='?',
    local_path="path/to/dir/{{ task_instance.xcom_pull(key='file_name', task_ids='py_task') }}",
    s3_path="path/to/s3/dir/{{ task_instance.xcom_pull(key='file_name', task_ids='py_task') }}"
)
```

**EDIT**

If you want to use BashOperator, `bash_command="echo {{ task_instance.xcom_pull(key='file_name', task_ids='py_task') }}"` should print file name to task log.